returning pointer to element of array, how does this affect garbage collection?
Let's say I have a function like this:
type Foo struct {
  F1 int
  F2 string
}

func ReturnMiddleElement() *Foo {
  foos = [4]Foo{Foo{F1:0,F2:"0",}, Foo{F1:1,F2:"1",}, Foo{F1:2,F2:"2",}, Foo{F1:3,F2:"3",}}

  return &(foos[2])
}

How would this affect GC? would this prevent the entire array from being collected? would it only prevent that one element from being collected? is there any reason that I should make an Array of Pointers instead with a struct this small, given this use case?

In your example, ReturnMiddleElement may be inlined and the foos array may be stored on the goroutine stack. The goroutine stack is not managed by the Go garbage collector. The gc Go compiler and tools provide a runtime library that includes a garbage collector (GC). If the foos array escapes to the heap, then the GC retains the entire array as long as there are any references to any array element.

Since you are holding a pointer into the array, the array and all its contents wouldn't be garbage collected. This is why slices.Delete zeroes out the end of the array.
With an array of pointers you create more objects and might increase the load on the garbage collector, only profiling can tell you what is better in your use case.
Generally, you shouldn't worry about minor memory usage until profiling indicates it's an issue. While it's possible to micro-optimize in many areas, it may be more beneficial to investigate why you're building an array when only a single element is needed for an extended period. If the pointer into the array is only required briefly, the garbage collector will eventually handle it.
Note that while not advisable, unsafe.Add(unsafe.Pointer(&foos[2]), unsafe.Sizeof(Foo{})) is a valid Go expression.
